# Magento 2 - How to request file with field name suffix

Tags: magento2, file-upload

I am trying to upload slide image in Magento 2. In some form I have suffix in name attribute for image field like this:

```
<input id="slide_image" name="slide[image]" class="input-file">
```

My question is how can request this file in following way as I am trying to request file like this:

```
$this->getRequest()->getFiles('image');
```

I have also tried these ways with no luck

```
$this->getRequest()->getFiles('slide[image]');
$this->getRequest()->getFiles('slide.image');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I got it working with this:

```
$this->getRequest()->getFiles('slide')['image']
```

Comment: how do you save this to module image folder?

Answer (score 2):

Just for information, if you want all the files inside the 'slide' array, you can use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getFiles('slide');
```

This will return a array with all the uploaded files.